# Azure media services encoding failed with error : 0x80131040

Tags: azure, service, encoding, media

I have some Azure media encoding jobs failing with the below error.
This is an error from azure backend side after the job has been submitted successfully.

> Task 'encode', Error : ErrorProcessingTask : Unexpected error when
>   setting up the Windows Azure Media Encoder task workflow:Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Platform,
>   Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that for some reason using the old encoding job preset names like **H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p** and the old processor name **Windows Azure Media Encoder** do not work anymore. Maybe it is temporary maybe not

I fixed the issue by using the processor name **Media Encoder Standard** and using a job config string like :

```
{
  "Version": 1.0,
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "KeyFrameInterval": "00:00:02",
      "StretchMode": "AutoSize",
      "H264Layers": [
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 3400,
          "MaxBitrate": 3400,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 1280,
          "Height": 720,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        },
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 2250,
          "MaxBitrate": 2250,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 960,
          "Height": 540,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        },
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 1500,
          "MaxBitrate": 1500,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 960,
          "Height": 540,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        },
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 1000,
          "MaxBitrate": 1000,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 640,
          "Height": 360,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        },
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 650,
          "MaxBitrate": 650,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 640,
          "Height": 360,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        },
        {
          "Profile": "Auto",
          "Level": "auto",
          "Bitrate": 400,
          "MaxBitrate": 400,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 320,
          "Height": 180,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        }
      ],
      "Type": "H264Video"
    },
    {
      "Profile": "AACLC",
      "Channels": 2,
      "SamplingRate": 48000,
      "Bitrate": 128,
      "Type": "AACAudio"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "{Basename}_{Width}x{Height}_{VideoBitrate}.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```